# Oracle Sproc Errors SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following sproc which compiles just fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SSACHDEV.SyncTeleappWithClientinfo
as
mine varchar2(1);
v_teleCaseNbr      number;
v_cashwithappyn varchar2(1);

CURSOR TeleAppCursor
is
    Select 
        distinct casenbr, cashwithappyn
    from TeleApp;

BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('begin');
open TeleAppCursor;

LOOP
    fetch TeleAppCursor into v_teleCaseNbr, v_cashwithappyn;
    EXIT when TeleAppCursor%NOTFOUND; -- this one has the problem

    Select cashwithappyn into mine from ClientInfo where casenbr = v_teleCaseNbr and trim(cashwithappyn) is null;

END LOOP;
dbms_output.put_line('end');
END;
```

But when I try to run it using the following:

```
BEGIN 
  SSACHDEV.SYNCTELEAPPWITHCLIENTINFO;
END;
```

I get the following errrors:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "SSACHDEV.SYNCTELEAPPWITHCLIENTINFO", line 21
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Anyone know why? Or what I can do to avoid these problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happening because the second `select` statement (`Select cashwithappyn into mine from ..`) in the procedure returns no data. Add `EXCEPTION` part in your procedure to handle that exception.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SSACHDEV.SyncTeleappWithClientinfo
as
mine varchar2(1);
v_teleCaseNbr      number;
v_cashwithappyn varchar2(1);

CURSOR TeleAppCursor
is
    Select 
        distinct casenbr, cashwithappyn
    from TeleApp;

BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('begin');
open TeleAppCursor;

LOOP
    fetch TeleAppCursor into v_teleCaseNbr, v_cashwithappyn;
    EXIT when TeleAppCursor%NOTFOUND;

    Select cashwithappyn into mine from ClientInfo where casenbr = v_teleCaseNbr and trim(cashwithappyn) is null;

END LOOP;
dbms_output.put_line('end');

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
  THEN  dbms_output.put_line(' no data found'); -- for example
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you whether sure the exception section should be placed outside the loop? I would rather placed it inside the loop. As for me the plsql should look like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SSACHDEV.SyncTeleappWithClientinfo
as
mine varchar2(1);
v_teleCaseNbr      number;
v_cashwithappyn varchar2(1);

CURSOR TeleAppCursor
is
    Select 
        distinct casenbr, cashwithappyn
    from TeleApp;

BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('begin');
open TeleAppCursor;

LOOP
    fetch TeleAppCursor into v_teleCaseNbr, v_cashwithappyn;
    EXIT when TeleAppCursor%NOTFOUND;
    begin
       Select cashwithappyn into mine from ClientInfo where casenbr = v_teleCaseNbr and trim(cashwithappyn) is null;
    when no_data_found then dbms_output.put_line('end');
    end;

END LOOP;

END;
```

But surely that stuff should be done in cursor itself using LEFT JOIN in order to not get DB gone nuts by huge numbers of small queries inside the loop.

Comment: Your way worked better, but he gave me the idea of the solution, I up voted you though :)